# python writing to html file with row enter between data frames

Tags: python, dataframe, file-writing

```
with open("a.html", 'w') as _file:
    _file.write(df_total_events.to_html())
    _file.write("ddddfhgfghfghfgh"+'\n')
    _file.write("\n")
    _file.write(""+"\n")
    _file.write("dddssssssssddd")
    _file.write(df_total_events.to_html())
```

I tried all options and still getting:

```
df_total_events table
ddddfhgfghfghfgh dddssssssssddd
df_total_events table
```

i want to have enough spaces between the data frames and Sentences:

```
    df_total_events table

    ddddfhgfghfghfgh

    dddssssssssddd


    df_total_events table
```

Comment: if it's a html file, I guess you need to use <br> for newline.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("a.html", 'w') as _file:
    _file.write(df_total_events.to_html())
    _file.write("ddddfhgfghfghfgh"+'<br/>')
    _file.write("<br/>")
    _file.write("<br/>")
    _file.write("dddssssssssddd")
    _file.write(df_total_events.to_html())
```

You can also add multiple line breaks "<br/>" together like this "<br/><br/>"